# XHTML img not showing up on page, but works in text editor

Tags: html, css, image, xhtml

I am using a HTML source editor to type and add images... The code I used to edit the font works perfectly fine, and so do the images..... but once I save and view my actual page http://www.youcaring.com/tuition-fundraiser/help-shelby-with-college/219039, the font is still correct, but the images don't display, they don't use the alt either, the img codes are simply showing fully as text. I'm not sure why the images show up IN the editor, but not on the main page.

I tried adding !doctype html and different ones for xhtml.. with the appropriate html, head, title, body tags and endings... but every time I save and view the page, the images are still only posted as text, and when I go to re-edit the code, the !doctype stuff I added as been automatically deleted.

I also tried changing any `"` `<` and `>` to `&quot;` `&lt;` and `&gt;` but still no luck.

I have the proper end tags on my img codes as well `/>`

All the images are proper http links and they are all working. I don't know what to try next!

Like mentioned earlier, the code works perfectly when it is in the text editor... and also when plugged into w3schools.com's tryit editor... but it doesn't work on the actual page I'm trying to put it on. Here is the img code:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://www.icandog.org/files/image/bristol-thank-you.jpg" alt="Thank You" width="500" /><br /><br />
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6rmkgje1w1ry7wi4o1_500.gif" alt="Thank You" width="500" /><br />
</div>
```

Here is what the img codes are showing up as: http://static.tumblr.com/rvqsweo/DrFnac1we/example.jpg

Comment: That code displays fine on a standard web page, so there's something else going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual page you are trying to put it on" and "works perfectly when it is in the **text editor**"? Are you viewing the file from your local computer from a web browser (**and if so which one**)? Are you uploading the file to web hosting? It is currently unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for the replies! Here is the actual webpage I used the code for (you can see the images I tried to put there and how they're just showing up as text):

Comment: http://www.youcaring.com/tuition-fundraiser/help-shelby-with-college/219039

Comment: ignore my fundraiser LOL, I'm just curious why the images won't show up?

Comment: I am using Chrome, and I also tried viewing the page on Firefox and nothing is different. Maybe the website doesn't allow img codes like this?

Comment: http://static.tumblr.com/rvqsweo/D9ynac0ps/dog.jpg here is a screencap of what the editor looks like, notice how the dog image is showing up

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the editor you are using. It is questionable whether it is on-topic here, but at least you should name the editor.

Comment: The page shows up OK now, does that mean you solved the problem? If so, what was it?

Comment: YEA, I accidentally solved the issue when I copied and pasted one of the img codes back into the editor.... it pasted strangely, putting odd spacing in spots of the code, as if I hit enter twice in a random spot of the code. Turns out, the picture shows up, so I simply added the same style of spacing throughout the rest of my code and all the images work! STRANGE right? I didn't have to edit the code at all, just add some enters .... here is an image of what i'm talking about: http://s24.postimg.org/4xytbm3hh/strange.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your source code I found something like the following:

```
&lt;img src="http://www.icandog.org/files/image/bristol-thank-you.jpg" alt="Thank You" width="500"&gt;
```

Instead of the diamond operator you used the entity reference of < and > in all the img elements. Change

```
&gt; and &lt;
```

To

> and < respectively and it will solve the issue

Comment: I noticed this also... I tried typing the code with < and > but the source code is automatically changed to &gt; and &lt;